# Custom Font Awesome CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome to create my form. But the FA icon comes with a filled color already. When I try to add the color, it is given to the entire icon. Is there a possible way to do this? Or should I be using any other unicode?

Note: I have to achieve this only by CSS. The parent component is not supposed to be configured. So I have to pass only a CSS class to achieve this. Please suggest me if there is any other unicode that I can use since the one that Im using dont really look like the one in the style guide

-Thank you very much!!

What I have:
[image: What I Have]

[image: What is supposed to be]

The first image is what I have. THe second image is how is it supposed to be like

`.exclamation-red .validation-tooltip-text:before {
    border: none;
    content: "\f06a";
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 12px;
    color: white;
}`

Please help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use fa-exclamation instead and you can style it within a round shape that you will add a white border to.

```
.validation-tooltip-text:before {
  content: "\f12a"; // http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/exclamation/
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:22px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  top: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/dMwwvz?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the FontAwesome icon isn't exactly what you want. For starters, it doesn't have a border, so even if you get the background color transparent, you won't have the white border.
I suggest creating the 'icon' yourself. Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="exclamation-circle">
    &#x21;
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.exclamation-circle {
    color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

you can play with the font-size, div width and height (make sure width = height to make it a perfect circle), and border thickness, but it should pretty much cover your needs.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k61gaf9z/

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I said, I was confined to only pass a CSS class.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggesting changing the icon class to [fa-exclamation](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/exclamation/). Alternatively you can change the unicode to `"\f12a"` and add a white border with border-radius. Set the width equal to the icon height and center the icon within.

Something like this:

```
.exclamation-red {
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: /* set this to the same as the icon height */
    text-align: center;
}

.exclamation-red:before {
    content: "\f12a";
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Feel free to fiddle around with the values in order to get closer to exactly what you're looking for.

Also if you weren't limited to only CSS, you could [stack](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked) the [exclamation](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/exclamation/) and [circle-thin](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/circle-thin/) icons

Comment: Im limited to only CSS. This seems to be doing the trick. Can you please correct me?

https://jsfiddle.net/vamshikrishna144/vqfbnns6/#&togetherjs=wEL5rUSwwD